# Creating TortoiseHg Trello integration with BugTraqProvider

Tags: plugins, tortoisesvn, tortoisehg

I like to make a BugTraq plugin for Tortoise Hg so I can select a card to link a commit to.

There isn't much out there on how to do this (kind of surprised it has not been done already).

I know you can use things like Zapier to read your commit message an then have a Card comment added referencing the commit, etc. That is great, that is what I am currently doing. But looking up the Card id all the time is annoying. I want a way to select the Card to link from the commit dialog.

I believe the way to go about this is the same as for all Tortoise(Hg|Git|SVN) is the same, you need a BugTraqProvider plugin. http://tortoisesvn.net/issuetrackerplugins.html . So I have been following this tutorial: https://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins/issue-tracker-plugins.txt. I restarted windows explorer after merging the generated registry file, and then restarted explorer.exe. But the drop down list for plugins is still empty in TortoiseHg settings.

Is there better documentation for doing this? Am I on the right track? Why does my plugin not show up?